# Getting stack affect to Android CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-cardview

I"m trying to get stack affect to my CardView , something like this :

[image: this stack should be dynamic , Visible or not , not the number of stack]

The logic solution suppose to be different background so i have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <size android:width="10dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" />
</shape>
```

but it does not work so i have a few questions :

1 . How do i get the original CardView background ? how will you look for that ?

2 . Can i get 3 card stack in the xml ?

3 . Other solution ? (I"m trying to avoid nested card views)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple xml file to get that kind of Ui. for getting the card view color use 
the tag cardview_light_background as background

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
tools:context="com.heavygari.dropdown.MainActivity">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/end_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/again_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cardview_custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]